# Jmeter Maven clean verify gives "Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonReader"

Tags: json, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to run jmx test using jmeter maven plugin. Everytime the tests starts and fails throwing  the below exception.
Exception: Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonReader

POM:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dap</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jmeter-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
       

          <jmeterExtensions>
            <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:0.19</artifact>
            <artifact>Kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras-libs:1.3.1</artifact>
            <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:jar:2.3</artifact>
            <artifact>com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0</artifact>
          </jmeterExtensions>
          <excludedArtifacts>

        <exclusion>net.minidev:json-smart:1.2</exclusion>
          </excludedArtifacts>
          <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>

        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
          </dependency>


        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you understand what NoClassDefFoundError means?

Comment: A method in a class that my code is looking for is not found. This is what is my understanding.

Comment: So, your classpath is broken.

Comment: how do I solve this?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of jars and classpath?

Comment: As per my understanding Jars are packages classes and other files, and classpath is the location for these classes provided to JVM. 
In this context i am sure where to correct this classpath. I did try removing all the classpaths and run maven command again, but in vain

Comment: The jar with these classes is not on the classpath when needed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks for your directions. Was able to solve this by upgrading to Kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras-libs to 1.4.0